# Firebase get Child Value after Query

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a firebase structure like one below:
[image]

I want to get the **'Shop'** of a person whose **'Phone'** is a particular value.

```
Query address=databaseReference.child("Users").orderByChild("Phone").equalTo(phone);
```

So the Query above is used, but...I do not know how to access the child of the result. After getting the query above, assuming the variable phone was **1234567890** how do I get the value of the **Shop** or **Email** of this particular user. I have tried different methods but I think I am not getting something right. :/

I think once I see a working example I would be able to apply it on mine.

Comment: did it work Charles, if not tell me so I can help you

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot Peter :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DatabaseReference address= 
database.getReference("Users").orderByChild("Phone").equalto(phone);

address.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
String value=data.child("Shop").getValue().toString();
}
}

 @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

You are querying on `Users`, then doing a condition `orderByChild("Phone").equalto(phone)`. So, its like you are doing `where Phone=value_phone`